# Uploading python libs to AWS lambda using Makefile

Tags: makefile, aws-lambda

I have been following a Youtube video to upload python libs on to AWS Lambda. The youtuber created this MakeFile, which created a folder called "package", in it a "tmp" folder and (PROJECT).zip:

```
install: virtual

build: clean_package copy_python build_package_tmp remove_unused zip

virtual:
    @echo "--> Setup and activate virtualenv"
    if test ! -d "$(VIRTUAL_ENV)"; then pip install virtualenv; 
virtualenv $(VIRTUAL_ENV); fi
    @echo ""

clean_package:
    rm -rf ./package/*

build_package_tmp:
    mkdir -p ./package/tmp/lib
    cp -R ./$(PROJECT)/. ./package/tmp/

copy_python:
    if test -d $(VIRTUAL_ENV)lib; then \
        cp -a $(VIRTUAL)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/;
    fi  

    if test -d $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib64; then \
        cp -a $(VIRTUAL)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/
    fi

remove_unused:
    rm -rf ./package/tmp/wheel*
    rm -rf ./package/tmp/easy-install*
    rm -rf ./package/tmp/setup-tools*

zip:
    cd ./package/tmp && zip -r ../$(PROJECT).zip .
```

I got this error on the Linux console:

```
$make -f Maketest.mk build
rm -rf ./package/*
if test -d envlib; then \
    cp -a /lib/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/; thenif test -d env/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/; fi
mkdir -p ./package/tmp/lib
cp -R ./AWS/. ./package/tmp/
cp: cannot stat './AWS/.': No such file or directory
Maketest.mk:21: recipe for target 'build_package_tmp' failed
make: *** [build_package_tmp] Error 1
```

The "package" is created, with only an empty "tmp".

PS: I am new to AWS Lambda, so if there is a better way to upload using the Linux console, I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a cleaner documentation on how to upload python dependent library files to lambda,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python

Hope it helps.

Comment: I first tried thru AWS guide and got stuck, after that I tried this video. I'll try AWS guide to see if I understand it better

Comment: At which step you got stuck?

Comment: I was able to upload it without creating that makefile. I assume the issue was with the file paths and using virtualenv to create the .zip folder. I redid the steps in the guide, made sure the file paths were correct. It worked    Thanks for helping

Comment: You are welcome. Please feel free to mark it answer if it solved your problem.